# Recursively find files with same name

Tags: linux, wordpress, find, rsync

Help me please to find duplicate files in different folders

I have 2 wordpress uploads directories:

with the same structure:

```
/uploads/2015/10/..
/uploads/2014/12/..
/uploads/somedir
..
```

Now I want to find all files with same path in 2 folders.
For example I can use **rsync** with -b flag, but i don't want to sync files right now.

Any relevant help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
diff -qr dir1/ dir2/

-q, --brief     report only when files differ
-r, --recursive     recursively compare any subdirectories found
    --no-dereference            don't follow symbolic links
```

Should do what you need.